# Is it possible to assign a shortcut key to fn+function key combination?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

I like to assign a shortcut to reload the page in chrome. But the fn keys are enabled by default. The f5 key is blank. If I disable the fn key enable then I lose the functionality of other keys like brightness control and media control. So is it possible to assign a shortcut key to one key combination fn+f5 as reload, so I can just press one key instead of two.

The hotkeys are like this
f1-help f2-brightness decrease f3-brightness increase f4-change display output **f5-blank** f6-mute f7-volume decrease f8-volume increase f9-previous f10-play/pause f11-next f12-flight mode